# How can i disable scroll to previous month in JTAppCalendar?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calendar, jtapplecalendar

Now Im using JTAppCalendar 6.0 version,

```
func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"

        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                                                 endDate: endDate,
                                                 numberOfRows: 6,
                                                 calendar: testCalendar, // This parameter will be removed in version 6.0
            generateInDates: .forAllMonths,
            generateOutDates: .tillEndOfGrid,
            firstDayOfWeek: .sunday)

        return parameters
    }
```

Comment: What is your startDate? Just set it to the actual date (Date()) and you won't be able to scroll to previous month. But this depends on what you need... give us some more infos please.

Comment: func rangeOfPeriod(period: Calendar.Component) -> (Date, Date) {
        
        var startDate = Date()
        var interval : TimeInterval = 0
        let _ = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: period, start: &startDate, interval: &interval, for: self)
        let endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(interval - 1)
        
        return (startDate, endDate)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just make your startDate start at the month you would like to begin scrolling at.